# No errors on Math.sqrt(-1)

Tags: python

Check out the following code, When I input a negative number, there seems to be no error, But square roots can't be negative, So I do not know why this happens.

```
import math
d=[]
while True:
    z=int(raw_input())
    if (z>0 and math.sqrt(z)): d.append(int(z))
```

On idle:

```
math.sqrt(int(-1))

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#16>", line 1, in <module>
    math.sqrt(int(-1))
ValueError: math domain error
```

Comment: Are you asking why the first code example doesn't act like the second?

Comment: Yeah, pretty much, Im not sure why there, isn't an error in the first code

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
    if (z>0 and math.sqrt(z)): ...
```

[Boolean operations short-circuit](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=short%20circuit#boolean-operations-and-or-not). This means that if `z > 0` is false, `math.sqrt(z)` is not evaluated. Hence no error.

P.S. Strictly speaking, square roots of a negative number exist and are [complex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number). Functions like `scipy.sqrt()` would happily return one of the complex square roots:

```
>>> import scipy as sp
>>> sp.sqrt(-1)
1j
```

Comment: Although square roots exist for negative numbers, there is no good choice for "the" square root. It's a bad idea to have `sqrt(-1)` evaluate to `1j`, since you then lose certain useful mathematical properties of `sqrt` (e.g. multiplicative homomorphism and continuity).

Answer (score 4):

There's no error because you're checking to make sure the value is positive.  The `and` operator short-circuits, meaning that if the first condition is false, the second is not evaluated.  You wrote `if z>0 and math.sqrt(z)`.  If `z` is less than or equal to zero, the second expression (the square root) is not evaluated, so you never attempt to take the square root, so there's no error.